# SSL Certificate IIS

Tags: ssl, iis, https, ssl-certificate

I have researched a lot before posting this question. I have a website that runs on **HTTP**. We are currently using ASP.NET webforms.
 My boss wants to update the payment gateway to use Stripe. Stripe wants the payments page to be running on HTTPS rather than HTTP. So I want to make my website **HTTPS**.

There are a lot of articles out there to make your website https with your own self signed certificate. However, I couldn't find relevant Microsoft docs for doing the same thing in a live production environment.

**My question is how would I do that in a production environment where you do not have ISS control?**. I understand that I will have to buy an SSL certificate from a verification authority. Currently I am using FTP to replace the bin files and the modified files to make changes to the website.

I was wondering if there are any C#,ASP.NET veterans out there who can guide me in the right direction.

Comment: The hosting companies have the option to buy ssl from them and add them to the website from plesk panel. You only have to work with redirections on web.config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run a web site with a certificate, which is a requirement to use HTTPS, you must be able to use IIS administrator to install the certificate on the web server and bind it to the web site on port 443. You could maybe possibly get it done without IIS admin by using PowerShell, but the user account running PowerShell would need the same permissions as if you did it with IIS admin.

Bottom line-- if you do not have any access to IIS admin at all, it is not possible to complete this task by yourself.

If your web site is hosted, you will need to approach the hosting service provider for instructions on how to request and install an SSL certificate for your web site.

Comment: I contacted my hosting providers. They told me that if I purchase an SSL Certificate, they might be able to install it on the Server. But still I will have to make changes in the code base as well right ?

Comment: Normally, no, there wouldn't be much to change in the code base, unless you have hardcoded links that use absolute URLs beginning with `http`. You might want to [modify some config](http://www.dotnetnoob.com/2010/11/how-to-secure-aspnet-cookies.html) to make sure your cookies are secure.